# Same repository names in different projects

Tags: bitbucket, project, bitbucket-cloud

I have two projects:

- CompanyAManagement
- CompanyBManagement

And for both projects, I would have a repository "frontend" and "backend".

However, after I have created the project "CompanyAManagement" and created both repositories in it, I can no longer create repository with the same names in my second project.

What would be the best practice to get along with this issue?

I come from gitlab where I have groups where repos are inside, this is possible there.

Answer (score 1):

In **Bitbucket Cloud** it's not possible to create Repository with same names in different Projects as well.

That's the ***downside*** of Bitbucket Cloud which I found in past.

And if you try to do so, it will remove repositories from first project and add in in it second project.

Thanks